# What is the "not less than" operator in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

Hear me out here. I tried to do \nless which I found online, however I was just given and undefined control sequence error message. What should I do?

Comment: You need to load `amssymb` for `\nless`.

Comment: Thank you. I was using amsmath and I thought that would be enough.

Comment: you may find `\not \lt` gives you what you are looking for

Comment: The title of the question sounds weird. I'd recommend to change it to understand the question more easily. What about: What is the not less than operator in LaTeX?

Comment: When I come across a macro that is undefined, I often just come to this site and use the search feature on the macro name.  If you can find a question or answer here where it is used, the MWE will always point you towards which package to load.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Go to [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) and draw what you want:

[image]

1. the symbol is `\nless`
2. you need `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Comment: Note that some fonts and their supporting `.sty` files already include the `\nless` symbol without having to load `amssymb`. Among these are Lucida Bright (`\usepackage{lucidabr}`) and MathTime Pro 2 (`\usepackage{mtpro2}`).

Comment: Is there a use case where this would be preferable to the "greater or equal" sign ?

Comment: @Rphad ? (I don't understand your comment)

Comment: In maths, saying that 3 is not < 2 is equivalent to saying 3 >= 2. So I wonder why one might use `not <` instead of `>=`

Comment: Ah, ok. That is probably a matter of style, personal preferences or similar things.

Comment: @Rphad @Rmano It is also a matter of context: If I am checking if `a<b` and my test say it is not, I would prefer to indicate it with this `\nless` (thinking about statistical tests).

Comment: If we're working in a partial order that is not a linear order, then it's possible for $x \nless y$ to be true but $x \geq y$ to be false.

For example, if we are dealing with functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ordered pointwise, then $f \nless g$ is true iff there is some $x$ such that $f(x) \geq g(x)$; $f \geq g$ is true iff for every $x$ we have $f(x) \geq g(x)$.