# How to get small phi φϕ?

Tags: greek

I'm using fouriernc font package, I saw that it has two different phi's. ϕ which is just $\phi$, but how do I get φ?

Comment: Welcome! Try `$\varphi$`... (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450709/38080)

Comment: Thank you so much! @Rmano