# How do I write this letter (showed in picture)

Tags: letters

How do I write this letter (showed in picture)

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450709/38080

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara)

Comment: it is `\mathcal{L}` by the way. From `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Comment: @Roland `\mathcal` is a kernel command and does *not* require `amssymb`.

Comment: @campa thanks...noted...Detexify told me to load it.